# detect if requests to PDF files

Tags: c#, web-crawler, bots

I would like to detect if requests to PDF files are from bots. We have PDF file on the site and record traffic to the PDF files using Inserts into a database for reporting. We store HTTP_USER_AGENT,HTTP_SESSION and LogDate. From looking at the database this looks like it is coming from a bot but I am not sure how to detect?

> Is there a way to detect if request are bot vs users?

```
    04:08:07.680    1.pdf   87f6fdb7-c1a9-4d9d-876f-e800d0fe619a    SameIPAddress   192.168.3.201   Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows) 2020-01-02
    04:08:11.213    2.pdf   87b18096-dc95-4ab4-a67d-22c08fdb22af    SameIPAddress   192.168.3.201   Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows) 2020-01-02
    04:08:12.493    3.pdf   55cd5c40-c167-4059-971f-b6aec54a1673    SameIPAddress   192.168.3.201   Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows) 2020-01-02
    04:08:14.903    4.pdf   49001c85-3a4d-47dc-8632-fb681cb26d2a    SameIPAddress   192.168.3.201   Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows) 2020-01-02
    04:08:15.293    5.pdf   a7fe9350-7470-48b3-ad12-7f7dd61c1896    SameIPAddress   192.168.3.201   Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows)
```

Comment: I don't know how your users access the pdf files - but the time between accesses does seem to be reasonable for a person if the files are simply listed - the only one which looks fast is the last one at nearly 0.3 secs - but over 3secs between the first two seems incredibly slow if it were a bot.

Comment: @PaulF they are listed on an APSX page but people do have the option to access them using the links. So would anything under 30 secs be a bot?

Comment: In theory, it is not possible - there is nothing a human could do a bot couldn't do, unless you want to assume getting all the PDFs indicate a bot?

Comment: @Jefferson: display your ASPX page in a browser & see how quickly you can go through the links using the middle mouse button to open in new tab - I've just done that for 6 links on this page in around 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either user agent information or IP address - safely assuming multiple clicks in milliseconds from same IP are bots, but the ideal thing to do will be to check if its a user or bot BEFORE storing the information in the database. Like a captcha or another verification.

More information here:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51091/how-to-detect-bots-clicking-a-link

Comment: what would be another verification other then captcha ?

Comment: Checkbox? like reCAPTCHA

Comment: Yeah I just didnt want to make the site unfriendly